# How to enable parallel execution of SimGrid simulation

Tags: simgrid

According to [Running user code in parallel](http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/simgrid/3.13/doc/options.html#options_virt_parallel) I launch my simulation as following:

```
./simulator platform.xml deployment.xml --cfg=contexts/nthreads:2
```

But I have an error:

```
Segmentation fault.
Segmentation fault (core dump)
```

Then I tried to add `ptask07` model into `main`, hoping that it would help:

```
MSG_config("host/model", "ptask_L07");
```

Now my simulation hangs after several job execution.

Maybe I should add some additional configurations to enable parallel execution of code? (when I run code without `contexts/nthreads` it works without errors.)

**UPD**:
My backtrace is. Supposedly, it tries to find moint point:

```
#0  0x00007fe7bfa9e418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007fe7bfaa001a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007fe7c0674933 in xbt_abort () at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/xbt/xbt_main.cpp:172
#3  0x00007fe7c062e9eb in simgrid::surf::HostImpl::findStorageOnMountList (this=0x19de7d0, mount=0x1da5d20 "\240\017\334\001")
    at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/surf/HostImpl.cpp:181
#4  0x00007fe7c062f3bd in simgrid::surf::HostImpl::close (this=0x19de7d0, fd=0x1b0a7d0) at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/surf/HostImpl.cpp:261
#5  0x00007fe7c060cbc2 in surf_host_close (host=0x19de210, fd=0x1b0a7d0) at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/surf/surf_c_bindings.cpp:192
#6  0x00007fe7c0598d70 in SIMIX_file_close (fd=0x19ed230, host=0x19de210) at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/simix/smx_io.cpp:142
#7  0x00007fe7c0598c61 in simcall_HANDLER_file_close (simcall=0x1d81a70, fd=0x19ed230, host=0x19de210)
    at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/simix/smx_io.cpp:130
#8  0x00007fe7c05ae517 in SIMIX_simcall_handle (simcall=0x1d81a70, value=0) at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/simix/popping_generated.cpp:349
#9  0x00007fe7c058fc58 in SIMIX_run () at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/simix/smx_global.cpp:502
#10 0x00007fe7c053b93c in MSG_main () at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/msg/msg_global.cpp:96
#11 0x0000000000407524 in main (argc=5, argv=0x7ffcac2a7708) at /home/ubuntu/LHCb/grid_simulation/main.cpp:51
```

Comment: We need a backtrace to diagnose the issue. Run your code in gdb or valgrind and tell us what's going on.

Comment: @MartinQuinson Done.

Comment: This is a bug in SimGrid. Please report it to our github bug tracker. Sorry about that.